# How do I style all elements with Javascript? No Jquery (2 examples in description)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got 2 scripts written with Javascript. The script have to result the same, but they don't. How do I write the Jquery function .css() in Javascript, so I'll get the same results?

SCRIPT 1(NOT working):

```
numItems = 0;

function addItem() {
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    var addLink = document.createElement('a');

    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    var text = input.value;

    addLink.innerHTML = text;
    menu.appendChild(addLink);
    addLink.setAttribute('href', text+'.html');

    numItems++;
    var itemWidth = (100/numItems)+'%';
    addLink.style.width = itemWidth;
}
```

SCRIPT 2(Working, BUT with jQuery!):

```
function addItem() {

    var numItems = $("#menu a").length+1;

    var itemLink = document.createElement('a');
    var input = document.getElementById('itemName');
    var text = input.value;

    itemLink.innerHTML = text;
    document.getElementById('menu').appendChild(itemLink);
    itemLink.setAttribute('href',text+'.html');

    var itemWidth = (100/numItems);

    $("#menu a").css("width", itemWidth+"%");

}
```

(PS. I just want to know, to improve my Javascript knowledge and to know how the Jquery .css() function is build.)

Comment: Actually I don't see why this line shouldn't work... Did you check your error console?

Comment: In the first snippet you only adjust the width of the newly created `a` Element, in the second you will change ALL the links. has nothing to do with the css() function, but how you select the range of objects that it is applied to.

Comment: You would have to loop over all the children of `menu` and apply `.style.width = itemWidth;` to them. Because thats what your jQuery code does.

Comment: The style is changing by each element added, but the previous elements don't change when a new element is added. So the first element will get a width of 100%, the second an element of 50% and so on. The thing is, i want all elements the same width. So: when there are 4 elements, i want all elements 25%, and not 1 with 100%, 1 with 50%, 33.3% and 25%.

Comment: @Werner: its getting incremented before that division takes place, so `100/1`

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the responses! My problem is solved, and now I know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the widht of all items

```
var numItems = 0;

function addItem() {
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    var addLink = document.createElement('a');

    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    var text = input.value;

    addLink.innerHTML = text;
    menu.appendChild(addLink);
    addLink.setAttribute('href', text + '.html');

    numItems++;
    var itemWidth = (100 / numItems) + '%';
    var as = menu.querySelectorAll('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
        as[i].style.width = itemWidth;
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/79evS/)

Comment: yep! should be spaced.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This and the other answers really helped me!